# enum type with numeric constant

Tags: java

I'm getting data from a legacy system where a certain one byte field is a code that may contain a letter or a number.  I want to map it to an enum but I'm not sure how to handle the numeric values.

```
public enum UsageCode {
    A ("Antique"),
    F ("Flood Damaged"),
    N ("New");
//  0 ("Unknown")  How to allow for value of "0"?

    private final String description;

    UsageCode(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Comment: ENUMS should be used as constants and not as dynamic values. You should be better off using your own implementation.

Comment: @Abhishek, it is a good and perfectly valid practice to represent a known and finite range of (primitive) values with an enum.

Comment: @peter-torok I agree on finite ranges but he is trying to retrieve te values from a database so my assumption was the values are not known only the Range(A-Z & 0-9) is known.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn it inside out:

```
public enum UsageCode {
    ANTIQUE ('A'),
    FLOOD_DAMAGED ('F'),
    NEW ('N');
    UNKNOWN ('0')

    private static final Map<Character, UsageCode> charToEnum
            = new HashMap<Character, UsageCode>();

    static { // Initialize map from legacy code to enum constant
        for (UsageCode code : values())
        charToEnum.put(code.getCode(), code);
    }

    // Returns UsageCode for legacy character code, or null if code is invalid
    public static UsageCode fromLegacyCode(char code) {
        return charToEnum.get(code);
    }

    private final char code;

    UsageCode(char code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public char getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}
```

For converting the incoming character codes into enum values, I added an inner `Map<Character, UsageCode>` and a static conversion method.

Example adapted from [*Effective Java 2nd Edition*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Item 30.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I also need to be able to print a description for each value so I guess I could so something like:  ANTIQUE ('A', "Antique") and update the constructor.

Comment: @Tom, indeed, you can freely add further properties (or even polymorphic behaviour) to your Java enum.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it other way round, having a meaningful constant and storing legacy value representation:

```
public enum UsageCode {

   ANTIQUE("A"),
   FLOOD_DAMAGED("F"),
   NEW("N"),
   UNKNOWN("0");

   private String legacy;

   private UsageCode(String legacy) {
      this.legacy = legacy;
   }

   public static UsageCode toUsageCode(String legacyOutput) {
      for(UsageCode code : values()) {
         if (code.legacy.equals(legacyOutput)) {
            return code;
         }
      }
      return null;
   }
}
```